# C# - Get the Index of the last non-zero number of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of annual results which I would like to identify the index of the last non-zero value. The 0 values at the end are an artifact of how the data is provided and read in. The 0 values can appear anywhere in the data, possibly even all 0s.

`decimal[] results = { 0, 0, 39.59m, -17.83m, 73.52m, 0, 56.80m, -61.54m, 0, 0, 0, 0 }`

I've tried a few things but I keep ending up with the index of the value before the zero in the middle (e.g. 4, not 7).

Comment: `var index = results.Reverse().SkipWhile( x => x == 0 ).Count() - 1`.

Comment: Calling `.Reverse` is going to mutate the contents of the array.  When you finish, the answer will be wrong (since the array is now reversed)

Comment: @Flydog57, good point. Thanks for pointing that out. I will need the array maintained in the original order

Comment: Maybe... but in my head, using a `for` loop and iterating back from the end is the most *elegant* way.  @Hayden's extension method seems like a great way to do this.  And, he did it generically (but consider where T: IEquatable instead).

Comment: @Flydog57 `Reverse` does not mutate the array folks. Did you try it? This isn't [Array.Reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netcore-3.1), it's LINQ"s [Reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netcore-3.1). It returns an enumerator object that evaluates the array in reverse.

Comment: @JohnWu: I need to stop looking at SO from my phone.  You are right, it does not mutate the array (I was looking at `Array.Reverse`).  However, what it does (looking at the decompiled source) is duplicate the array and then use a `for` loop to iterate backwards over the newly copied array (it does the copy to get the data into an array, with is easily iterated backwards).  Unless I'm missing something, I don't see it skipping the copy if the source is an array.  I still stand that directly iterating over the array in reverse fashion is the best way (similar to Hayden's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the LINQ answer:

```
var index = results.Reverse().SkipWhile( x => x == 0 ).Count() - 1
```

Comment: Better test again then. LINQ doesn't mutate anything. Perhaps you are confusing it with `Array.Reverse()`. I've tested it and the original array is not touched.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension method which can generically handle `LastIndexOf` functionality.

```
public static class CustomExtensions
{
    public static int LastIndexOf<T>(this T[] input, Func<T, bool> selector) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        int lastIndex = -1;

        for (int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
        {
            if (selector(input[index]))
            {
                lastIndex = index;
            }
        }

        return lastIndex;
    }
}
```

With this, you're essentially only updating the `lastIndex` variable if the value at the index matches the condition (i.e. not equal to 0)

**Usage**

```
decimal[] results = { 0, 0, 39.59m, 17.83m, 73.52m, 0, 76.80m, 61.54m, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int index = results.LastIndexOf(num => num != 0);

// Output is 7
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me although i needed the first element ans so I just swapped to  int index = results.FindIndex(num => num != 0);

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal[] results = { 0, 0, 39.59m, -17.83m, 73.52m, 0, 56.80m, -61.54m, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

This approach uses a minimum of code

```
var index = Array.FindLastIndex(results, value => value != 0);
```

This approach gives you both the value and the index

```
var lastIndexAndValue = results
  .Select((value, index) => (index, value))
  .LastOrDefault(item => item.value != 0);
```

Comment: Sorry to be a noob, how do I then get each number out of lastIndexAndValue to use separately later in the code?

Comment: @Dave F: Updated my answer with an additional approach that uses less code than the other answers.

Comment: For even less code, use a value tuple. `.Select((value, index) => (index, value)).LastOrDefault(item => item.Item1 != 0)`

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Your code did not do the job, but I got the idea, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to iterate through the array with a `for` loop.
This should work:

```
int LastNonZero = -1;
for (int count = 0; count < results.Length; count++) {
  if (results[count] != 0) // It isn't zero:
  {
    LastNonZero = count;
  }
}
```

I just tested this and it returned 7.

Comment: This does work. Which gets me thinking (rare these days), I assume another approach might be to determine the length of the array then traverse through it from the last item back towards the beginning, and exit once a non-zero value has been found. Faster?

Comment: Possibly. I guess you could do it like this: `for (int count = results.Length; count > 0; count++) { if (results[count] != 0) { return count; } }`

Answer (score 1):

I would just convert to `List` and use `linq`.

```cs
var result = results.ToList().LastIndexOf(results.Last(c=> c != 0));
```

If you do not want to convert to list.

```cs
var index = Array.LastIndexOf(results,results.Last(c=> c != 0));
```

Comment: What if the last non-zero number also appears elsewhere in the array?

Comment: @ZevSpitz yes you are right, I changed to `LastIndexOf`.

Comment: This copies all the data into a new structure.  Arrays work with `for` loops **really** well.

Comment: Take an array with a million elements.  The last non-zero element is number 999,993.  With a for loop, you iterate seven (plus or minus one) elements.  With your solution, you copy all that data into a list, and do whatever LastIndexOf does (which, who knows, may start from the beginning)

Comment: @Flydog57 "a million elements" is your assumption, he did not ask the most performance way though.

Answer (score 0):

one problem of LastOrDefault alone is that you cannot distinguish whether last index 0 is a real index, or when value was not found.

Maybe this could help:

```
decimal[] results = { 0, 0, 39.59m, -17.83m, 73.52m, 0, 56.80m, -61.54m, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
Console.WriteLine(results.Select((value, index) => (index:index + 1, value)).LastOrDefault(item => item.value != 0).index - 1);
7
```

and

```
decimal[] results = { 0, 0 };
> Console.WriteLine(results.Select((value, index) => (index:index + 1, value)).LastOrDefault(item => item.value != 0).index - 1);
-1
```